# Unfamiliar syntax in Java method declaration

Tags: java, android, methods, syntax, declaration

I am following a tutorial that does not explain the syntax of this method declaration. Can someone explain what the first <T> right after the static keyword is for? When I hover over it in Android Studio is just says, "Class T extends Object".

```
public static <T> Resource<T> success(@NonNull T data) {
    return new Resource<>(Status.SUCCESS, data, null);
}
```

Comment: It is a [generic parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html).

Comment: Is this a case of it being a [Bounded Type Parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)? If I understand this correctly, this limits the arguments that can be passed to this method to type T. Is that correct?

Comment: Every generich parameter is - at least implicitly - bounded. The implicit bound is always `Object`.